# Remove table rows updating total data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where I can add multiple numbers and create an `add more` button also to add a new row on the table and calculate all total using jQuery. Now when I remove the new row, the total value is not updated, but when I click some of the `input fields` and then it is updated. Now my question is

> How can I make the total value auto-update when the row is removed.

Below is my code:

```js
function addMore() {
  var new_raw = $('<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding:0px;" class="remove">Remove</a><td><input type="number" class="addData"></td></tr>');
        new_raw.insertBefore('#my_new_raw');
        $("#myTable").on('click', '.remove', function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
}


$(document).on('blur keyup', '.addData', function(e) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.addData').each(function(i) {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('addData')) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        }
    });
    $('#my_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table" id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="addData"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="addData"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="my_new_raw">
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addMore()">Add More</a></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td><input type="number" readonly id="my_total"></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> I know I didn't call a function to update the total, because I don't know how. Help me here. Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `blur` and `keyup`, the total will not be changed when changing the number value with arrow. I prefer `input` event instead. You can trigger the `input` event when clicking on **Remove**:

```
$('.addData').trigger('input');
```

**Working Code Example:**

```js
function addMore() {
  var new_raw = $('<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding:0px;" class="remove">Remove</a><td><input type="number" class="addData"></td></tr>');
  new_raw.insertBefore('#my_new_raw');
  $("#myTable").on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    $('.addData').trigger('input');
  });
}

$(document).on('input', '.addData', function(e) {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.addData').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('addData')) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    }
  });
  $('#my_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table" id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="addData"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="addData"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="my_new_raw">
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addMore()">Add More</a></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td><input type="number" readonly id="my_total"></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**OR:** By using a function

```js
function addMore() {
  var new_raw = $('<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding:0px;" class="remove">Remove</a><td><input type="number" class="addData"></td></tr>');
  new_raw.insertBefore('#my_new_raw');
  $("#myTable").on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    updateTotal();
  });
}

$(document).on('input', '.addData', function(e) {
  updateTotal();
});

function updateTotal(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('.addData').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('addData')) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    }
  });
  $('#my_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table" id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="addData"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="addData"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="my_new_raw">
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addMore()">Add More</a></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td><input type="number" readonly id="my_total"></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I used this trigger event in around 25 functions in one page and removing the rows is very slow, any suggestions?

Comment: @Vpa, it is really difficult to tell why the code slows down without experiencing the code.....Though I am not sure, you can try create a function and call that like NoobTW did in his answer.....

Comment: using function is nice, it doesn't take too much time like before, thank you very much

Comment: @Vpa, it is really grate to know that time issue is solved by using function. Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Simply `calculate` again.

Your calculate way is already good, just wrap it with a function, and then you can call it whenever you want to.

```js
function addMore() {
  var new_raw = $('<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding:0px;" class="remove">Remove</a><td><input type="number" class="addData"></td></tr>');
        new_raw.insertBefore('#my_new_raw');
        $("#myTable").on('click', '.remove', function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            calculate();
        });
}

function calculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.addData').each(function(i) {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('addData')) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        }
    });
    $('#my_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}


$(document).on('blur keyup', '.addData', function(e) {
    calculate();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table" id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="addData"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="addData"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="my_new_raw">
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addMore()">Add More</a></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td><input type="number" readonly id="my_total"></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple wrap the calculate code as function .And use [`closest()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp) instead of `parent().parent()`

```js
function addMore() {
  var new_raw = $('<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding:0px;" class="remove">Remove</a><td><input type="number" class="addData"></td></tr>');
  new_raw.insertBefore('#my_new_raw');
}


function calc() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.addData').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('addData')) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    }
  });
  $('#my_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}

$(document).on('blur keyup', '.addData', function(e) {
   calc();
}).on('click', '#myTable .remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  calc();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table" id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="addData"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="addData"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="my_new_raw">
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addMore()">Add More</a></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td><input type="number" readonly id="my_total"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you so much, but i'll go for others answer... instead of calling more function..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function addMore() {
        var new_raw = $('<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="padding:0px;" class="remove">Remove</a><td><input type="number" class="addData"></td></tr>');
        new_raw.insertBefore('#my_new_raw');
        $("#myTable").on('click', '.remove', function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            var sum = 0;
            $('.addData').each(function (i) {
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('addData')) {
                        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#my_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
        });

    }


    $(document).on('blur keyup', '.addData', function (e) {

        var sum = 0;
        $('.addData').each(function (i) {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                if ($(this).hasClass('addData')) {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                }
            }
        });
        $('#my_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
    })
</script>
```