# Table total auto-calculated when the newly expanded row is removed using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So my snippet gives me this error: `this.closest is not a function` but everything works fine in my page, so let's forget this part.

My question is I have a table where the column and rows can be auto-calculated when user input some values, referring this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52642412/8826120 comment. And now I am making add more button and all the functions are working fine(adding the new input values), but when I removed the new rows, it cannot auto-calculated the total values.

> How can I make my total line auto-update when the newly expanded row is removed?

You can check it from below, but as I said before only on this page I've got `error:this.closest is not a function`. Thanks in advance

Note: I make the function like this [Remove table rows updating total data using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035432/remove-table-rows-updating-total-data-using-jquery)

```js
$(document).on('input change', '.outstanding, .received, .paid', updateTable);

function updateTable() {
  updateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
  updateCol($(this).closest("td"), $(this));
  updateTotal($(this.closest("table")));
}

function updateRow($row) {
  var sum = 0,
    sum2 = 0,
    sum3 = 0;
  $row.find('.outstanding, .received, .paid').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('outstanding')) {
        out = $(this).val();
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('received')) {
        reci = $(this).val();
        sum2 += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('paid')) {
        paid = $(this).val()
        sum3 += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    }
  });
  $row.find('.amtOutstanding').val(sum + sum2 + sum3);
}

function updateCol($col, $input) {
  var index = $col.index() + 1;
  var sum = 0;
  $col.closest('table').find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')').find('input').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0 && !$(this).attr('id')) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });

  if ($input.hasClass('outstanding')) {
    $('#sch26_outstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  } else if ($input.hasClass('received')) {
    $('#sch26_received').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  } else if ($input.hasClass('paid')) {
    $('#sch26_paid').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  } else if ($input.hasClass('amtOutstanding')) {
    $('#sch26_amtOutstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  }

}

function updateSchedule26() {
  var sum = 0,
    sum2 = 0,
    sum3 = 0,
    out, reci, paid;
  $('.outstanding, .received, .paid').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('outstanding')) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('received')) {
        sum2 += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('paid')) {
        sum3 += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    }
  });
  var total = (parseInt(out) + parseInt(reci)) + parseInt(paid);
  $(".amtOutstanding").val(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_outstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_received').val(sum2.toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_paid').val(sum3.toFixed(2));
}

function updateTotal($table) {
  var sum = 0;
  $table.find('.amtOutstanding').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  $('#sch26_amtOutstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2))
}

function addMoreDepIT() {
  var new_raw = $(
    '<tr>'+
      '<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove">Remove</td>'+
      '<td><input type="number" min="0" name="" id="" class="form-control outstanding"></td>'+
      '<td><input type="number" min="0" name="" id="" class="form-control received"></td>'+
      '<td><input type="number" min="0" name="" id="" class="form-control paid"></td>'+
      '<td><input type="number" min="0" name="" id="" class="form-control amtOutstanding" readonly></td>'+
    '</tr>'
  );
  new_raw.insertBefore('#addMore');
  $("#dep_it_table").on('click', '.remove', function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      updateTable();
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-sm" id="dep_it_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Name</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Outstanding</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Received</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Paid</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Sub Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control outstanding"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control received"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control paid"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control amtOutstanding" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control outstanding"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control received"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control paid"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control amtOutstanding" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr id="addMore">
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:0px;" onclick="addMoreDepIT()"><i class="ft-plus hidden-lg-up"></i>&nbsp;Add More</a></td>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Add Total</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_outstanding" class="form-control total_sum" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_received" class="form-control total_sum" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_paid" class="form-control total_sum" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_amtOutstanding" class="form-control" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set all input of removed row to 0 and then recalculate every col and row total then you remove the row:

```
$("#dep_it_table").on('click', '.remove', function() {
      var row = $(this).closest('tr');
      row.find(".outstanding, .received, .paid").each(function(){
         $(this).val(0)
         $(this).change();
      });
      row.remove();
});
```

```js
$(document).on('input change', '.outstanding, .received, .paid', updateTable);

function updateTable() {
  updateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
  updateCol($(this).closest("td"), $(this));
  updateTotal($(this.closest("table")));
}

function updateRow($row) {
  var sum = 0,
    sum2 = 0,
    sum3 = 0;
  $row.find('.outstanding, .received, .paid').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('outstanding')) {
        out = $(this).val();
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('received')) {
        reci = $(this).val();
        sum2 += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('paid')) {
        paid = $(this).val()
        sum3 += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    }
  });
  $row.find('.amtOutstanding').val(sum + sum2 + sum3);
}

function updateCol($col, $input) {
  var index = $col.index() + 1;
  var sum = 0;
  $col.closest('table').find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')').find('input').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0 && !$(this).attr('id')) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });

  if ($input.hasClass('outstanding')) {
    $('#sch26_outstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  } else if ($input.hasClass('received')) {
    $('#sch26_received').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  } else if ($input.hasClass('paid')) {
    $('#sch26_paid').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  } else if ($input.hasClass('amtOutstanding')) {
    $('#sch26_amtOutstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  }

}

function updateSchedule26() {
  var sum = 0,
    sum2 = 0,
    sum3 = 0,
    out, reci, paid;
  $('.outstanding, .received, .paid').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('outstanding')) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('received')) {
        sum2 += parseFloat(this.value);
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('paid')) {
        sum3 += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    }
  });
  var total = (parseInt(out) + parseInt(reci)) + parseInt(paid);
  $(".amtOutstanding").val(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_outstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_received').val(sum2.toFixed(2));
  $('#sch26_paid').val(sum3.toFixed(2));
}

function updateTotal($table) {
  var sum = 0;
  $table.find('.amtOutstanding').each(function(i) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  $('#sch26_amtOutstanding').val(sum.toFixed(2))
}

function addMoreDepIT() {
  var new_raw = $(
    '<tr>'+
      '<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove">Remove</td>'+
      '<td><input type="number" min="0" name="" id="" class="form-control outstanding"></td>'+
      '<td><input type="number" min="0" name="" id="" class="form-control received"></td>'+
      '<td><input type="number" min="0" name="" id="" class="form-control paid"></td>'+
      '<td><input type="number" min="0" name="" id="" class="form-control amtOutstanding" readonly></td>'+
    '</tr>'
  );
  new_raw.insertBefore('#addMore');
  $("#dep_it_table").on('click', '.remove', function() {
      var row = $(this).closest('tr');
      row.find(".outstanding, .received, .paid").each(function(){
        $(this).val(0)
        $(this).change();
      });
      row.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-sm" id="dep_it_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Name</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Outstanding</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Received</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Paid</th>
      <th style="width:16.67%">Sub Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control outstanding"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control received"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control paid"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control amtOutstanding" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control outstanding"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control received"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control paid"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="" class="form-control amtOutstanding" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr id="addMore">
      <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:0px;" onclick="addMoreDepIT()"><i class="ft-plus hidden-lg-up"></i>&nbsp;Add More</a></td>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Add Total</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_outstanding" class="form-control total_sum" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_received" class="form-control total_sum" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_paid" class="form-control total_sum" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="sch26_amtOutstanding" class="form-control" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working perfectly... Thank you so much. Didn't think I have to go like this... Now my `error:this.closest` is also gone, can you tell me what is the problem of this error?

Comment: updateTable() this function expect an input element. but when you call it in the remove event $(this) is an event object, that was the problem of error:this.closest

Comment: the above answer is not working on my project anymore. I don't understand why, before it is working perfectly, but the total cannot auto calculate again. do you have any idea? @Mustapha Larhrouch